# Is there a recommended limit for an array in a Context in React?

Tags: react-native, performance

I have an array in my context. That array receives a new object quite frequently. I could end with thousands of elements in a few minutes.

Is there any recommended size for that array to avoid performance issues?

Comment: did you find the answer to this?

Comment: @AmandaConda, I ended up storing the elements of the array in a DB, then I just update the id in the context.